# Check_Time in show table status

Tags: mysql

We have MYSQL running in production.
Recently we noticed few changes on one of the table.
We checked few information using " Show Table status" command.
We noticed Check_time column on that table had a new value. I mean no other table have that column populated, but this one had a value of date and time.
We have MyISAM enegine.

My question is:
Can you please let me know, what does that Check_time indicate. I read it does this "When the table was last checked".
"Checked" mean in layman words. Checked is "queried"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a result of `CHECK TABLE` being performed, in which case the new value in question should indicate that the table was reviewed, or "queried".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html